# How do I compile a .cpp file on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm fairly comfortable with Linux and compiling things - I normally just follow the instructions and can manage to get myself out of trouble. This time, I was given a .cpp file by a random Internet citizen and I would really like to know how to compile it. Everything I seem to try (g++, c++, gcc) doesn't seem to work.

Anyhow, here's the file: http://pastebin.ca/2073013

Edit: Updated with verbose output from `g++ file.cpp -o whatever`: http://pastebin.ca/2073052

Comment: What errors do you get with g++?

Comment: For future reference, you should always copy into your question any error messages, warnings, etc. verbatim. Often we can tell exactly what's wrong with the code with just a glance of the error messages. It will help us reply with better and quicker answers.

Answer (score 29):

You'll need to compile it using:

```
g++ inputfile.cpp -o outputbinary
```

The file you are referring has a missing `#include <cstdlib>` directive, if you also include that in your file, everything shall compile fine.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `-o outputbinary` bit isn't required. (If it's not there, GCC will default to `a.out`)

Comment: Adding that line and running that command gives me crazy output/errors: http://pastebin.ca/2073052

Comment: You should of course also remove everything after and including line 117 -- the lines after that point are not a part of the given C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you that there are problems starting at line 122 in the middle of that strange FBI-CIA warning message.  That message is not valid C++ code and is NOT commented out so of course it will cause compiler errors.  Try removing that entire message.

Also, I agree with In silico: you should always tell us what you tried and exactly what error messages you got.

Answer (score 0):

Just type the code and save it in .cpp format. then try "gcc filename.cpp" . This will create the object file. then try "./a.out" (This is the default object file name). If you want to know about gcc you can always try "man gcc"